# E11000 : MongoDB how do I get rid of this error

Tags: mongodb

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection:
```

So I understand why I am getting this error, but our system requires the index of the users UUID.

So is there away to either a) solve this so it is coded correctly that it does not throw this error.

B) disable this message - it's not useful.

query causing it:

```
 const userData = {"UUID": uuid, "ipaddress":ip};
   
  
        var update = {'$push':{
          "history.$.endtime":Date.now()
        }};
      

        Listeners.findOneAndUpdate(
          {"UUID": uuid, "ipaddress":ip, "history.HID":hid},
          { $set: { "history.$.endtime":Date.now() } }, function(err) {
          if (err) {
              console.log('ERROR when submitting round');
              console.log(err);
          }
      });
```

Comment: You can make rebuild the index without the `unique` constraint to silence the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove

```
 unique: true
```

from your `Listeners` schema.
Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

seems, UUID field have unique index. That's why you are getting this error. If you don't want uniqueness for this field. Then drop existing index and create again without unique constraint

> db.collection.dropIndex("UUID");
>
> db.collection.createIndex({UUID:1});